# Use Female USB Type A as Power Supply for external device

Tags: power, arduino-pro-mini

I bought a female USB Type A Breakout, like this (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12700). I thought I could use this one to simply power a USB 5v water pump. Therefore I use an external USB power supply that is regulated by a relay, that I regulate with my Arduino. But I'm wondering if it is possible to get that USB Breakout to "give out" power to my water pump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Just connect VCC to +5V and GND to GND and you can plug a 5V device into it.

If you need to use it as a charge port (for charging a phone) you will need to connect the D+ and D- pins together.

Comment: I thought that too, but it's not working. Whats the difference between a charge port and my case?

Comment: A charge port tells the device how much current it can supply. A dumb device like a pump won't need it.

Comment: But do you have an idea, why it's not working? I use a FTDI USB plug, that I stick into a USB  Power Adaptor(with direct link to usb pump works). Then I connect VCC and GND to the usb female breakout.

Comment: ok simple as it is sometimes... there was a bad manufactoring soldier. i fixed it and now its running. thanks a lot!